# How do I Map several controlled input checkboxes from an array in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, checkbox

I'm trying to make a number of controlled checkboxes from an array like so

```
const subjects = [
    {
      name: 'WebDev',
      label: 'Web Development',
    },
    {
      name: 'GraphicDesign',
      label: 'Graphic Design',
    },
    {
      name: 'Engineering',
      label: 'Engineering',
    },
  ];
```

I want to make them *controlled*, so for the checked attribute, I need it to be controlled by state. But how do I loop through them and access the correct object in state each time? I guess I could maybe parse the subject.name string, but surely that is not good practice? Indeed, I could perhaps make a matching array in my state where the indexes match up, but I don't feel like that is scalable and relies heavily on correct order.

```
{subjects.map((subject, i) => (
  <div className="w-full sm:w-auto" key={i}>
  <label className="flex content-center p-3">
    <input type="checkbox" name={subject.name} value={subject.name} onChange={onInputChange} checked={????}/>
    <span className="ml-3">{subject.label}</span>
  </label>
</div>
))}
```

I also have other inputs like this. For them, it is easy because I can just use `state.name` to control them.

```
      <input id="name" type="text" value={state.name} onChange={onInputChange} name="name" required/>
```

I then use a generalised function to update the inputs. This takes use of the `useState()` Hook

```
    const onInputChange = e => {

    const item = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.type === "checkbox" ? e.target.checked : e.target.value;

    setState({
      ...state,
      [item]: value,
    })
  }
```

What is the best practice in React for approaching something like this? If I could contain the subjects in my state as shown below it would be good.

Should I maybe be ditching the seperate array and containing all the information in state?

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
    name:'',
    email: '',
    message: '',
    checkedSubs: {
      WebDev: false,
      GraphicDesign: false,
      Engineering: false
    },
    emailSent: false
})
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered adding another property to your subject objects? Something like `checked: false`?

Comment: Where does this `subjects` array come from?  Is it a prop of the component?  Does it change?

Comment: If you want to use the same `onInputChange` to handle the checkboxes then they would need to be top-level properties of the state, not nested.  `checked={state[subject.name]}`.

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple states to track the state of the subjects and your general data. Give each subject an extra property called `check` which should hold a boolean value. This value will determine the checked state of your checkboxes.

In the `onInputChange` function update the `subjects` state with the new checked state of the input.

Add a `useEffect` hook which has a dependency: the `subjects` array. Whenever the value of `subjects` changed it will trigger the logic inside of the `useEffect` callback function. In that function update your general state based on the values in the `subjects` array.

The end result will be that the `subjects` array will determine your inputs. Whenever an input is changed the `subjects` state will be updated. Then when the `subjects` changes, the inputs will be rerendered and the values in `data` will be updated based on the change.

```
const ExampleComponent = () => {
  const [ subjects, setSubjects ] = useState([
    {
      name: 'WebDev',
      label: 'Web Development',
      checked: false
    },
    {
      name: 'GraphicDesign',
      label: 'Graphic Design',
      checked: false
    },
    {
      name: 'Engineering',
      label: 'Engineering',
      checked: false
    },
  ]);

  const [ data, setData ] = useState({
    name:'',
    email: '',
    message: '',
    checkedSubs: {
      WebDev: false,
      GraphicDesign: false,
      Engineering: false
    },
    emailSent: false
  });

  const onInputChange = e => {
    const item = e.target.name;
    const isChecked = e.target.checked;

    const updatedSubjects = subjects.map(subject => {
      if (subject.name === item) {
        return {
          ...subject,
          checked: isChecked
        }
      }

      return subject;
    });

    setSubjects(updatedSubjects);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setData({
      ...data,
      checkedSubs: subjects.reduce((acc, cur) => {
        acc[cur.name] = cur.checked;
        return acc;
      }, {})
    });
  }, [subjects]);

  return (
    subjects.map(({ name, label, checked }, i) => (
      <div className="w-full sm:w-auto" key={i}>
        <label className="flex content-center p-3">
          <input type="checkbox" name={name} value={name} onChange={onInputChange} checked={checked}/>
          <span className="ml-3">{label}</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    ))
  )
}
```

Comment: If the checked state in its own state `subjects` then it should not also be in the `data` state.  I see that they asked for this but it doesn't make sense.  Just create a `formData` variable that combines `subjects` and `data` instead of having to use `useEffect` and do a second state update which isn't necessary.

Comment: @LindaPaiste I agree. Combining it all in a single object will be much easier without any workarounds. However, for the purpose of demonstrating the usage of `useEffect`, I believe that this is an acceptable scenario of how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Universal `onInputChange`

Your current `onInputChange` handler updates a property in `state` based on the `name` property of the `input`.  One of the easiest ways for you to implement this is to let this handler update the checkboxes as it would any other field.

This means that your subjects would become top-level properties of `state`.  This is fine as long as there is no chance that a subject name is the same as a form field like `"email"`.  You can rearrange the `state` however you want into some other variable.

You can map to your example format:

```
// can't use variable subjects because it's already defined
const {name, email, message, emailSent, ...subjectBooleans} = state;

const formatted = {name, email, message, emailSent, subjects: subjectBooleans}
```

You can get an array with the names of the checked subjects only:

```
const checkedSubjects = subjects
  .filter(o => state[o.name])
  .map( o => o.name );
```

I'm not sure where the `subjects` array is coming from and if it's a constant or something that might change.  You can just omit these properties from your initial state and assume that `undefined` means `false`/unchecked.  We see if a subject is checked by looking at `state[subject.name]` and we can explicitly cast to a `boolean` with `!!` to better handle this `undefined` scenario.

```
const MyForm = ({ subjects }) => {
  
  // removed initial values for subjects
  // you could set these, but they aren't required
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    message: "",
    emailSent: false
  });

  // no changes to this function
  const onInputChange = (e) => {
    const item = e.target.name;
    const value =
      e.target.type === "checkbox" ? e.target.checked : e.target.value;

    setState({
      ...state,
      [item]: value
    });
  };

  return (
    <form>
      <input
        id="name"
        type="text"
        value={state.name}
        onChange={onInputChange}
        name="name"
        required
      />
      {/* ... other inputs ... */}
      {subjects.map((subject, i) => (
        <div className="w-full sm:w-auto" key={i}>
          <label className="flex content-center p-3">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              name={subject.name}
              value={subject.name}
              onChange={onInputChange}
              checked={!!state[subject.name]}
            />
            <span className="ml-3">{subject.label}</span>
          </label>
        </div>
      ))}
    </form>
  );
};
```